# How to test if localStorage receives item I set in a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

Currently trying to run a unit test for a authentication function. I've written a dummy function that basically does what the authentication function for the sake of abiding by NDA.

**Authentication.js**

```
export const myTestFunction = param => {
  console.log(param);
  localStorage.setItem("Test", param)
}
```

**index.test.js**

```
import {myTestFunction} from "../../redux/actions/ApiAuthAction";

const localStorageMock = {
    getItem: jest.fn(),
    setItem: jest.fn(),
    clear: jest.fn()
  };
  global.localStorage = localStorageMock;

test("Test to see myTestFunction sets localStorage to the param value", () => {
    let param = "Hello"
    myTestFunction(param);
    expect(localStorageMock.setItem).toBeCalledWith("Test");
});
```

When I run the test, this is what it returns:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(expected)

    Expected mock function to have been called with:
      ["Test"]
    But it was not called.

      73 |     let param = "Hello"
      74 |     myTestFunction(param);
    > 75 |     expect(localStorageMock.setItem).toBeCalledWith("Test");
         |                                      ^

      at Object.toBeCalledWith (src/__tests__/reducers/index.test.js:75:38)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I am creating a mock localStorage. I threw the function into the test and it still throws this failed test of it not being called. Help?

EDIT: The whole point of this test is to see if that `localStorage.setItem("Test, param);` gets called or not.

Comment: You expect it to be called with "Test", but call it with "Hello"

Comment: @NineBerry The test is for `localStorageMock.setItem` and that method is called with `.setItem("Test", param)`

Comment: @NineBerry I tried ```expect(localStorageMock.setItem).toBeCalledWith("Hello");``` and I am getting the same result. The point of the test is to make sure that ```localStorage.setItem("Test", param)``` function gets called.

Comment: Okay. You expect it to be valled with "Test", but call it with "Test", "Hello". I suppose that jest differentiates between calls with one and two parameters.

Comment: I suspect this line is not actually replacing the `localStorage` instance from the `ApiAuthAction` module: `global.localStorage = localStorageMock;`

Comment: @WillCain I console logged it after calling it in that test case and it shows: ```console.log src/__tests__/reducers/index.test.js:77
    undefined```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up using was: `expect(localStorage.getItem("Test")).toBeDefined();` but I am happy to hear if anyone has a more dynamic solution.